# How to expand $\frac1{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^5)}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

How do I expand

> $$\frac1{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^5)}$$

I need to find the coefficent of $x^9$, but I also want to be able to derive the general form. The only method I could thing of was to expand the $3$ individual denominators into an infinite GP and then count the number of ways I can get $x^9$, but not only is that time consuming, I cannot get a general formula for it. Can you please help me?

Comment: @Groverkss How is expanding into the GP time-consuming? You can simply substitute $x^2$ and $x^5$ after you write down the series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$. The fact that you only need the $1$ and $x^5$ coefficients for $\frac{1}{1-x^5}$ makes your problem even easier.

Comment: @mrtaurho  There is the $x^9$ term in the expansion, though.  This is the expansion up to $x^{10}$: $$1+x+2x^2+2x^3+3x^4+4x^5+5x^6+6x^7+7x^8+8x^9+10x^{10}\,.$$

Comment: @TobyMak I am unable to understand what you mean. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Batominovski How did you find that?

Comment: @Groverkss I'll write up an answer shortly.

Comment: @Groverkss Never mind, others posted answers before I could post mine. I hope this is what you need.

Comment: I would say it is easier to compute the expansion coefficients combinatorially.  The coefficient $t_k$ of $x^k$ in $$f(x):=\dfrac{1}{(1-x)\,\left(1-x^2\right)\,\left(1-x^5\right)}$$ is the number of solutions $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ to the equation
$$x+2y+5z=k\,.$$

Comment: Thus, $z\leq \left\lfloor\dfrac{k}{5}\right\rfloor$, $y\leq \left\lfloor\dfrac{k-5z}{2}\right\rfloor$, and $x=k-2y-5z$.  This means
$$t_k=\sum_{z=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}{5}\right\rfloor}\,\Biggl(\left\lfloor\frac{k-5z}{2}\right\rfloor+1\Biggr)=\left(\sum_{z=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}{5}\right\rfloor}\,\Biggl(\left\lfloor\frac{k-z}{2}\right\rfloor-2z\Biggr)\right)+\left\lfloor\frac{k}{5}\right\rfloor+1\,.$$
Therefore,
$$t_k=\left(\sum_{z=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}{5}\right\rfloor}\,\left\lfloor\frac{k-z}{2}\right\rfloor\right)+1-\left\lfloor\frac{k}{5}\right\rfloor^2\,.$$

Comment: So, it may be easier if you look at $k$ modulo $10$.  That is, compute $t_{10m}$, $t_{10m+1}$, $t_{10m+2}$, $\ldots$, $t_{10m+9}$ separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We expand $\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^5)}$ without using complex  roots. This is  somewhat cumbersome, but nevertheless  feasible. We start with a *[partial  fraction  decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)* of  $\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)}$ which has only                             real valued  roots in the denominator.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)}}&=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2(1+x)}\\
> &=\frac{A}{1-x}+\frac{B}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{C}{1+x}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{4(1-x)}+\frac{1}{2(1-x)^2}+\frac{1}{4(1+x)}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^j+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=0}^\infty (j+1)x^j+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^jx^j\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(2j+3+(-1)^j\right)x^j}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we do the partial fraction decomposition using an Ansatz with unknown constants $A,B$ and $C$.
- In (2) we calculate the constants by multiplying out and comparing coefficients of equal powers of $x$ (or we ask Wolfram Alpha for support).
- In (3) we expand the first and last expression using the *geometric series* expansion and use for the middle term the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-2}{j}(-x)^j=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \binom{j+1}{j}x^j=\sum_{j=0}^\infty (j+1)x^j$$
- In (4) we collect the terms with equal powers in $x$.

> We are now ready for multiplying and expanding with $\frac{1}{1-x^5}$.  We obtain  from  (4)
>   \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^5)}}\\
> &\quad\qquad=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left(2j+3+(-1)^j\right)x^j\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{5k}\\
> &\quad\qquad=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{{j+5k=n}\atop{j,k\geq 0}}(2j+3+(-1)^j)\,x^n\tag{5}\\
> &\quad\qquad=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{j=0}^n\left(10j+3+(-1)^j\right)x^{5n}\right.\\
> &\quad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad+\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(10j+5+(-1)^{j+1}\right)x^{5n+1}\\
> &\quad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad+\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(10j+7+(-1)^{j}\right)x^{5n+2}\tag{6}\\
> &\quad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad+\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(10j+9+(-1)^{j+1}\right)x^{5n+3}\\
> &\quad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad+\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(10j+11+(-1)^{j}\right)x^{5n+4}\Bigg)\\
> &\quad\qquad=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{l=0}^4\sum_{j=0}^n\left(10j+3+2l+(-1)^{j+l}\right)x^{5n+l}\tag{7}\\
> &\quad\qquad=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{l=0}^4\left(10\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+(3+2l)(n+1)+(-1)^{l}\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}\right)x^{5n+l}\tag{8}\\
> &\quad\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{l=0}^4\left((n+1)(5n+3+2l)+(-1)^{l}\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}\right)x^{5n+l}}\tag{9}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> and we have found a (let's say)  nice series expansion.  We can now harvest and calculate  the coefficient $[x^9]$ from $\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^5)}$ by setting $n=1$ and $l=4$ in (9) to get
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^9]}&\color{blue}{\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^5)}}\\
> &=[x^9]\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{l=0}^4\left((n+1)(5n+3+2l)+(-1)^{l}\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}\right)x^{5n+l}\\
> &=\frac{1}{4}(1+1)(5+3+8)+(-1)^4\frac{1+(-1)^1}{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=8}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (5) we multiply the series  using the Cauchy product.
- In (6) we rearrange the series  according to residue  classes $\mathrm{mod}   \ 5$. The first  series  with $x^{5n}$ corresponds  to  $j$-values being  multiples of $5$: $j=0,5,10,\ldots$.  The next  series with $x^{5n+1}$  corresponds  to $j=1,6,11,\ldots$, etc.
- In (7) we use a slightly more compact notation and write the $5$ parts by summing up over $l=0,1,2,3,4$.
- In (8) we do some simplifications using the formulas: $\sum_{j=0}^n c=(n+1)c$ and $\sum_{j=0}^n j=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. We also  see that summing up $(-1)^j$  gives  the  sequence $1,0,1,0,1,\ldots$.
- In (9)  we finally collect corresponding terms.

Answer (score 2):

In
$$(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\cdots)(1+x^5+x^{10}+x^{15}+\cdots)$$
the degree $9$ is obtained when

$$p+2q+5r=9$$

and you need to find the number of solutions. We have

$$(0,2,1),(1,4,0),(2,1,1),(3,3,0),(4,0,1),(5,2,0),(7,1,0),(9,0,0)$$
hence the coefficient is $8$.

---

Let $f(n)$ denote the number of admissible solutions of

$$a+2b=n.$$

It is not a big deal to establish

$$f(n)=\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor+1.$$

Now let $g(n)$ denote the number of solutions of

$$a+2b+5c=n.$$

We have

$$g(n)=\sum_{c=0}^{\lfloor\frac n5\rfloor}f(n-5c)=\sum_{c=0}^{\lfloor\frac n5\rfloor}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n-5c}2\right\rfloor+1\right).$$

With $q:=\lfloor\frac n5\rfloor+1$, this sum is

$$\frac{nq}2-\frac{5(q-1)q}4+q-\left\lfloor\frac q2\right\rfloor.$$

This result is obtained by temporarily ignoring the floor, summing, then correcting as half of the terms were exaggerated by $\frac12$.

(Caution: this formula might be in error by $\frac12$ depending on the parity of $n$.)

Comment: @Groverkss: the approach restates the problem in terms of a Diophantine equation. Read this: https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00074944/PDF/RR-1616.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you settle down and actually do it, it is not that time consuming.
So you have $\frac1{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^5)}$ here. Expanding each factor gives:
$$
\frac1{1-x^n}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^{in}.$$
In order to find the ways you can get $x^8$, just count how many ways you can get $8$ by combining (adding, because exponents add when multiplied, i.e. $x^2x^5x^1=x^{2+5+1}=x^8$.) $1,2$ and $5$. This follows directly from the expansion process. You can get the following:
$$
\begin{align}
8&=1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1\\
&=1+1+1+1+1+1+2\\
&=1+1+1+1+2+2\\
&=1+1+2+2+2\\
&=2+2+2+2\\
&=1+1+1+5\\
&=1+2+5.
\end{align}
$$

Hopefully, I haven't missed any combination, and in that case, there will be 7 ways. So the coefficient of $x^8$ is $9$.

In fact, this formula is quite important when studying **partition numbers**, that is, how many different ways there are to break a natural number into sums of positive integers. The number of ways to partition $n$ would then be the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of
$$
\prod_{m=1}^\infty \frac1{1-x^m},
$$
whose proof is left as an exercise for you.